# MMDrawerController where I need to add sidemen buttons?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mmdrawercontroller

I am junior iOS dev and trying to use MMDrawerController.

I have `MainStoryboard` with 4 views.

- NavigationController (embed on CenterViewController controller)
- CenterViewController
- LeftViewController
- AboutViewController

I've added button on Navigation left item on `CenterViewController` and tap on it open/close my sidemenu.

But if I wan't to change center view with this code

```
ViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AboutViewController"];
                if (vc)
                    [appDelegate.drawerController setCenterViewController:vc withCloseAnimation:YES completion:nil];
```

It works fine but I have no navigation left button. Why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is:

```
AboutViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AboutViewController"];
            if (vc)
            {
                if ( [appDelegate.drawerController.centerViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]] )
                {
                    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
                    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)appDelegate.drawerController.centerViewController;
                    [appDelegate.drawerController toggleDrawerSide:MMDrawerSideLeft animated:YES completion:nil];
                    [navController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
                }
            }
```